# Asm snippet from a disassembled program

Tags: assembly

Could anybody explain the meaning of the following code I found in a disassembled function?

```
mov     eax, [ebx+20h]
mov     ecx, [eax]
mov     [eax], ecx
mov     ecx, [eax+4]
mov     [eax+4], ecx
```

To me seems like the memory pointed by eax and eax+4 is going to be overwritten with the same values that were stored in the same memory locations before the execution of the code snippet... which doesn't really make sense 0_o. What am I missing ?

Comment: I didn't use X86 ASM in years, but it seems that yeah, this code doesn't make much sense at all.. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mov eax,[ebx+20h] ; move the memory constant at address [ebx] with the offset of 32 bits

mov ecx,[eax]  ; move the memory constant at address eax with no offset


mov [eax],ecx ; mov the address at ecx to value of eax

mov ecx,[eax+4] ; mov teh value of eax with offset 4 to ecx

mov [eax+4],ecx ; move the adress at ecx to the value of eax with offset 4
```

[eax] in like *eax in C

Comment: It looks [more like NASM than GAS style](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html), just by looking at `mov eax, [ebx+20h]` followed by `mov ecx, [eax]`. I think it's `mov destination, source` here.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you are right, values at `eax` and `eax + 4` (or `ebx + 20x` and `ebx + 24h`) are read and written with no change. This might be a way to force the CPU loading them and some words around into its 1st level cache.

Comment: it might also be due to lack of optimization.